# IPhone, Audio MP3 or M4A audio file plays no sound

Tags: iphone, audio, ios7

I'm trying to play a sound method within the object `didSelectedIndex` `UITableViewController`

The audio files are files with extension `m4a`, but I also tried with mp3 files and the result does not change.

Below I post the code that I have implemented in the method of TableViewController:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *soundFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/testaudio.m4a", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    NSLog(@"soundFileURL %@",soundFileURL);
    NSError *error;
    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:&error];

    if(!player){
        NSLog(@"ERRORE: %@",error);
    }
    [player setDelegate:self];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];

}
```

I also tried directly on the device and it still does not play any sound.

I also added a class AVSession as follows:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setActive:YES error:nil];
```

The result did not change, does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (tested):

Set a *property* for your `AVAudioPlayer` object in your `.m`:

```
@property(strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

Then add this in your:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *soundFilePath;

    if ((soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testaudio" ofType:@"m4a"]))
    {
        NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
        NSError *error;
        self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:&error];

        if(self.player)
        {
            [self.player setDelegate:self];
            [self.player prepareToPlay];
            [self.player play];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"ERRORE: %@", error);
        }
    }
}
```

You don't need `AVAudioSession` in your case.

Comment: Great...now play sound